# How to read input into list of exact length given in different lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, stdin

Input - 
    6
    14
    2
    54
    13
    11
    67
    89
    98
    79

```
import sys
n=int(input()) #entering number of elements
lst=[int(x) for x in sys.stdin.readlines(n)] #takinginput
print(lst)
```

output:

```
[14, 2]
```

expected output -

```
[14,2,54,13,11,67]
```

Comment: `[int(x) for x in n.split()]`? To get 1st 6 elements use *slicing*.

Comment: i need only 6 elements from the input into list and the remaining for other operation, is there any solution other than taking the whole input into the list and slicing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you also use `input` for the second input:

```
import sys
n=int(input()) #entering number of elements
lst=[int(input()) for x in range(n)] #takinginput
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.stdin.readlines(n)` means "read no more than n characters". **Not** lines.

Comment: almost correct, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.readlines

Comment: @KennyOstrom characters or bytes, right. Still **not lines**.

Comment: Hey, I might be picky but I'm not petty! It's important that it can read more than n characters. It only checks the count after reading each full line. But your answer is just a comment -- it needs the documentation link and maybe a little exposition. I was trying to help you out. (It is a good comment though)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

def ReadNLines(n):
    List =[]
    for line in range(n):
        List.append(int(sys.stdin.readline().replace('\n','')))
    return List


n=int(input('input')) #entering number of elements
list = ReadNLines(n)
print(list)
```